# Magento 2: CSV Importing issue ,import successfully and did't show any products

Tags: magento2, import, products, csv

While importing product CSV Magento didn’t give any error and import successfully. but didn’t show any products on customer view.

If products already added it didn’t update the product content.
I also have remove cache, re-indexing, browser cache also use in incognito  but no success.

Comment: Verify that the products are loaded in the admin panel and that you have set a stock value for each of them greater than 0.

Comment: @NicolaLepetit not showing on admin site and also not showing on customer view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSV files must use UTF-8 encoding.**

if you have special character in your csv file (specially in description column ) you have to save your CSV files must use UTF-8 encoding.
other wise it will import successfully and did't give any error. it's mostly happen in windows Operating system